# GtkLabel doesn't display newlines from file

Tags: c, gtk, label, getline

I would like to update a GtkLabel with data imported from a text file, but it doesn't evaluate `\n` as a newline character, as it should normally do.
The file contains (for example):

```
This is a\nnewline.
```

**How do I get this `\n` understood by GtkLabel ?**

This is my complete code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *label, *window;
  gchar* test_char;
  ssize_t len;
  FILE* fh;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Test GTK");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 100);

  label = gtk_label_new ("");

  fh = fopen ("file.txt", "r");
  getline (&test_char, &len, fh);

  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (label), test_char);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), label);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  fclose (fh);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is converting the literal \n to \n.

There are two ways to do this I can come up with (I leave out the file reading part):

Text in test file:

> That's\na\ntest,\nfolks!

**1.**

```
gchar *new_txt = g_strcompress (test_char);
gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (label), new_txt);
g_free (new_txt);
```

**2.**

```
GRegex *regex = g_regex_new ("\\\\n", 0, 0, NULL);

gchar *new_txt = g_regex_replace (regex, test_char, -1, 0, "\\n", 0, NULL);

gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (label), new_txt);

g_free (new_txt);
g_regex_unref (regex);
```

Note that you have to escape twice: first for C, then for the regex engine, so that the latter sees: replace \\n with \n. You have to escape both backslashes of \\n for C, that's why you get four backslashes in the string that has to be replaced.

**Result for both:**

[image]

Both ways need a newly-allocated string to store the converted text, so you have to free the memory after usage.

Comment: Wonderful, I didn't know `g_strcompress ()`

BTW, does anyone could explain (or refer me to a documentation) when and why I must free() memory ?

Comment: Me neither, I just looked up the string functions in the GLib docs to see if there is something.

Comment: As for freeing memory, it is usually stated in the official docs of GLib and GTK, but unfortunately not always. I had to look into the GTK sources once or twice to be sure.